# Fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 boots straight to Grub menu

Tags: grub2, 18.04, 18.10, grubrescue

After reinstalling a fresh copy of Ubuntu 18.10 and 18.04 3 times, I have come with the constant issue of being greeted to the Grub menu, even though I'm only booting Ubuntu on its own. I've used boot-repair, update-grub, modifying the grub files manually, then updating grub, but nothing's helped. In fact, it's only made things worse.

Comment: Is windows installed too? Have you changed any BIOS settings?

Comment: Have you tried setting timeout=0 in /boot/grub/grub.cfg?

Comment: Artube, no this is a single boot of Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: C.S.Cameron, I just tried that, I'm afraid that did nothing even after running 'sudo update-grub'

Comment: C.S.Cameron, nevermind, after editing both '/etc/default/grub/' AND '/boot/grub/grub.cfg', grub finally stopped showing and I can actually boot my system uninterrupted. thank you!